# Approximation using the total derivation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, approximation

I want to approximate $8.98\sqrt{9.98-1.02}$.

But I don't know. What is the function $f$?

Comment: Typically, this kind of problem is presented as an application of the local linearization of a function.  In this case, I am guessing that the idea is to approximate the square root function by its local linearization (i.e. the tangent line through, perhaps, $(9,3)$.  More context is required to give a better answer than that.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if we change the numbers slightly, we end up with
$$
9 \sqrt{10 - 1} = 27
$$
which is easy to find.  So, we can approximate $8.98\sqrt{9.98-1.02}$ using $9 \sqrt{10 - 1}$.

Now, call the numbers which we changed $x,y,z$.  We can say that the above two expressions are values of the function $f(x,y,z) = x \sqrt{y - z}$: the expression which we want to approximate is $f(8.98,9.98,1.02)$, while the expression with slightly different values is $f(9,10,1) = 27$.

With the above in mind, we should approximate $f(8.98,9.98,1.02)$ using the linear approximation to $f(x,y,z) = x \sqrt{y - z}$ about the point $(x,y,z) = (9,10,1)$.

Comment: $f_x(x,y,z)dx + f_y(x,y,z)dy + f_z(x,y,z)dz =\sqrt{y-z}dx + \frac{x}{2\sqrt{y-z}}dy+\frac{-x}{2\sqrt{y-z}}dz\approx f(x+dx, y+dy, z+dz)-f(x,y,z)$